# Class using generics extending interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

So I'm rolling my own max heap and I'm doing something wrong with using a generic class extending an interface. Say I have a class like this:

```
class SuffixOverlap:IComparable<SuffixOverlap>
{
    //other code for the class
     public int CompareTo(SuffixOverlap other)
    {
        return SomeProperty.CompareTo(other.SomeProperty);
    }
}
```

And then I create my heap class:

```
class LiteHeap<T> where T:IComparable
{
    T[] HeapArray;
    int HeapSize = 0;
    public LiteHeap(List<T> vals)
    {
        HeapArray = new T[vals.Count()];
        foreach(var val in vals)
        {
            insert(val);
        }
    }

    //the usual max heap methods
}
```

But when I try to do this:

```
LiteHeap<SuffixOverlap> olHeap = new LiteHeap<SuffixOverlap>(listOfSuffixOverlaps);
```

I get the error:
`The type SuffixOverlap cannot be used as a type parameter T in the generic type or method LiteHeap<T>. There is no implicit reference conversion from SuffixOverlap to System.IComparable.`

How do I create LiteHeap as a class that uses generic class T implementing IComparable so I can write `new LiteHeap<SomeClass>` and it will work where SomeClass implements IComparable

Comment: `IComparable` is not `IComparable<SuffixOverlap>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` are different, completely-unrelated interfaces.

You need to change that to `where T : IComparable<T>`, so that it actually matches your class.

Comment: ... or have the class implement both `IComparable` and `IComparable<SuffixOverlap>` and implement it the same way you handle `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`'s implementation.